# virtualenv and python path

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

i did a virtualenv in c:\users\devtool.virtualenv\devenv
After i run activate.bat.

And last i wrote a simple py file to test environment:

```
 import os,sys
 for x in sys.path:
     print x

 print os.executable
```

and result is weird

```
C:\Users\devtool\.virtualenv\devenv\Scripts
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv-1.8.4-py2.7.egg
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg
C:\Users\developer\.virtualenv\devenv\Lib\site-packages\django
C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip
C:\Python27\DLLs
C:\Python27\lib
C:\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\Python27
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages

['C:\\Users\\developer\\.virtualenv\\devenv\\Lib\\site-packages\\django']

C:\Python27\python.exe
```

in fact it is just using base python install.
What is the point of using virtualenv?
i am getting errors with django, installed in virtualenv.

i can solve it, just need to rewrite django-admin.py to append to search path my virtualenv folder, but still what is need of virtualenv in this case.

another thing that i cant understand. In the python search path, there is a line

```
C:\Users\devtools\.virtualenv\devenv\Lib\site-packages\django
```

and when i use django-admin.py i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\devtools\.virtualenv\devenv\Scripts\django-admin.py", line 12, in module>
from django.core import management
ImportError: No module named django.core
```

but django folder is in the path

Answer (score 0):

virtualenv extends/overrides your system python environment with its paths prepended to the paths of the system python installation. You see, you .virtualenv site-packages are listed before the system site-packages, that's how it works.

The thing you have to keep in mind that `activate` patches your current command line environment, so you must run `activate` before running python code depending on your virtualenv.

Comment: this is interesting. i got the idea. In this case for some reason, installatin process of django or django-admin.py script itself - ammend python search path not correctly.

Comment: have you run django-admin from CLI after `activate` or from some kind of other shell (IDE or something)?

Comment: i did run from CLI. In fact django-admin.py which is in devenv/scripts/django-admin.py just refer or i could say launch django-admin.py script located in devenv/lib/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py.

Comment: check the PATH from inside the cli - .virtualenv\bin should be first to ensure the virtualenv'd python is found first

Comment: i wrote test file run.py and if I run it after activating virtualenv it gives me the correct path to python in .virtualenv/devenv/Script. In fact there is no problem with generating a new project. I can do it just simple use of full path to djando-admin.py. I am just trying to understand what is wrong happening. In fact this bug bothers people a lot and it is in djanog(with virtualenv) since i start to use django last 2 years.

Comment: it could be connected with wondows' way of associating file types with an executable. If you run bare django-admin.py, it would run it with system python.exe. If you run `activate` and then `python something-needs-django.py`, it should run it with the python from your `.virtualenv/bin`

Comment: As i sayd i checked it. I add some code into django-admin.py to print to console python path and it is used a right python.exe from virtualenv

Comment: in fact what i found is virtualenv activate file amend python path not correctly. you can see result that there is not site-packages folder from virtualenv in python path

Comment: there are some issues with python search path but still cant under stand why python cant find django.core folder. I import django-admin.py into pydev to try to debug but in pydev it works fine. And search path is ammended by pydev is right, so there is no exceptins.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue few days before. From the base folder, you have to execute the following command.

```
C:\Users\devtools\.virtualenv\devenv> python Scripts\django-admin.py startproject myproj
```

Comment: yeap it is one of solution but better to modify python search path in django-admin.py and append to it your virtualenv direcoty+/LIb/site-packages